# avplayer streaming works but not local file

Tags: swift, streaming, local, avplayer

I try to play local mp3 and if the local file is not present I'm streaming an URL. Simple case.
I can't figure out why streaming work but not playing a local file

```
let localURL = AudioManager.localFileFromURL(AudioManager.file)

if AudioManager.isFileDownloaded(localURL)
{
      self.player = AVPlayer(URL: NSURL(string: localURL)!)
      self.player?.play()

}else{
      self.player = AVPlayer(URL: NSURL(string: AudioManager.file)!)
      self.player?.play()
}
```

LocalURL is the url of the file on disk.

isFiledownloaded function is checking if the file is on the disk. I did verify that it returns true when the file is on disk.

AudioManager.file is an external URL.

When I play an external MP3 I get some sound but not from the local file.

Answer (score 0):

Finally found it :
For local files, don't use NSURL(string:) but NSURL(fileURLWithPath:)